# TaskPoolScheduler throws Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied (XP, Rx2)

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I'm using Reactive Framework 2 but it suddenly throws throws Win32Exception from TaskPoolScheduler on an XP machine, but it looks not reproducible. The stacktrace is quite limited, any idea?

```
2013-07-02 15:19:38,209 [31] ERROR MyUnhandledExceptionHandler : AppDomainUnhandledException
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
  at System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.<>c_DisplayClass2`1.<>cDisplayClass4.<Schedule>b_1()
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
  at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
  at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

It should be from Rx v1, since the callstack is so "empty":

```
// decompiled by ILSpy
public IDisposable Schedule<TState>(TState state, Func<IScheduler, TState, IDisposable> action)
{
    if (action == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    }
    SerialDisposable d = new SerialDisposable();
    CancellationDisposable cancellationDisposable = new CancellationDisposable();
    d.Disposable = cancellationDisposable;
    this.taskFactory.StartNew(delegate
    {
        try
        {
            d.Disposable = action(this, state);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception ex2;
            Exception ex = ex2;
            Thread thread = new Thread(delegate
            {
                throw ex; // Here
            });
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
        }
    }, cancellationDisposable.Token);
    return d;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: link: co-asked on [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/33182e8a-2ebb-4687-91cb-34693c18bcee/taskpoolscheduler-throws-win32exception-0x80004005-access-is-denied-xp-rx2)

Comment: Does it happen only on XP? Does your app use any uncomming things like hosting multiple AppDomains and passing jobs/delegates between them? Does your app tinker with useraccounts and impersonations? How many Threads does your pool have, maybe too many for the system's limits and maybe that's just coalesced pool overflow?

Comment: It only happened once (and it's on XP). No multiple AppDomains. Simple code without tinkering user accounts or impersonations. Doesn't manage threads manually so shouldn't be over limit.

Comment: If you can attach a debugger to the process you could always change your exception settings to break on throw rather than break on unhandled.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: the problem is it cannot happen in development and it only happened once on client's machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded Rx 2.0.3 and I cannot find `System.Reactive.Concurrency.TaskPoolScheduler.<>c_DisplayClass2'1.<>cDisplayClass4.<Schedule>b_1()`. The TaskPoolScheduler sits in the `System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll` (on all platforms), but it does not contain such subclasses/methods.

Which exact version of Rx do you use? Have you tried with the newest?

Comment: FYI: If google did not lie to me, the newest is [2.1 located here](https://rx.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Looks like the error is from Rx 1, the code is updated in the question.